# I am having a problem with using text mesh pro in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with using text mesh pro in Unity.
When I run the code I get two errors. one "The type or namespace name 'TMPro' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

and one: "The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TMPro;

public class enemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI  scoreTxt;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear. Assuming TextMeshPro is correctly installed, all you gotta do is include it correctly. It does not belong to the `UnityEngine` namespace.

Instead try:

```
using TMPro;
```